# How to install amd k7 kernel in ubuntu

Tags: kernel, ati

I tried to install amd K7 kernel in ubuntu 11.10 (64 bit) but E: Unable to locate package

```
sudo apt-get install linux-k7
sudo apt-get install linux-k7-smp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu does not provide processor specific kernels. If you are running a 64 bit version of Ubuntu then you are already running a kernel that will use the AMD K7 capabilities.

If you want a kernel compiled to match your specific processor then you will have to [compile your own kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile). But it's almost certainly not worth your while - the link has reasons for and against if you want to know more.